# Pass Image URI to another Activity

Tags: android

I have 2 activities and both have an Imageview,
I want to pass Image taken from camera/gallery on activty one to activity 2.
I don't want to pass Image itself I want to pass URI(and than set the uri to bitmap of activity 2 and Imageview) of the Image so it would consume less memory but I don't know the Way. Please Help Me.
PS: If image is not taken/not selected from Gallery the ImageView of Activity 2 should show "Nothing Selected"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply pass your image path as String in intent :

```
intent.putExtra("imagePath", imageFilePath);
```

Get image path from intent and load using BitmapFactory :

```
String imagePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePath");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
imageView.setImageDrawable(bitmap);
```

Comment: The "imageFilePath" is String Right? That is Converted from URI?

Comment: Yes is String and no need to convert URI.

Comment: change your last line of code to :
`imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);` for it to work